# How do I get multiple jquery attr values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

My code:
http://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/ecJDG

Basically what I want to get are all the data attribute values from the attr call **data-designer**

There are suppose to be 4 of them but I can only get the first one using:

```
  var dsad = $('ul').attr("data-designer");
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `each()` to interact with each element individually:

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('designer'));
});
```

Or you can use `map()` to create an array of all the values which you can deal with separately:

```
var designers = $('ul').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('designed');
});
console.log(designers);
```

Note, I used `data` to get the `data-*` attributes as this is quicker than accessing the attributes of the DOM element directly.

Comment: Are you sure that `data()` is faster than `attr()`? It should be slower, at least for the first call, since it has to enumerate all the `data-` attribute to build its cache.

Comment: I haven't done any specific testing but I believe jQuery builds the cache on DOMReady. I am ready to be proved wrong though ;)

Comment: From the source code, it looks like it's on the first call (and enumerating everything on DOMReady would lead to a noticeable performance loss IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('data-designer'))
    //you can add to an array also  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to project the attribute values into an array:

```
var designers = $("ul").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-designer");
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$('ul').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).attr("data-designer"));
});
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bAxwz)

Answer (score 1):

`$('ul').attr("data-designer")` just got the attribute for the first ul element. If to get all uls with `"data-designer"` attribute, try this:

```
 $('ul[data-designer]').each(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr("data-designer"));
 });
```